# How can I use HTML::FormFu for jQuery AJAX form validation?

Tags: ajax, perl, validation, html-formfu

Are there any examples I can look at that use [HTML::FormFu](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-FormFu) with AJAX form validation and submission? I would really not like to write my validation routines three times (once in JS, once in FormFu constraints, and once in DBIC models), so I'd really like a way that's integrated with HTML::FormFu::Model::DBIC if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery Validation Engine that submits form to PHP and returns the fancy error boxes if there is any validation required. Have a look at this link: [JQuery Validation](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoAjaxSubmitPHP.html)